# Finding next hop in CISCO-CDP-MIB

Tags: snmp, cisco, mib

I'm working on app to find routes between 2 address via SNMP.
The app needs to support multiple MIBs.
For MIB 2, I was able to query routing tables e.g ipRouteNextHop, etc.

In CISCO-CDP-MIB, is it possible to find next hop address?
If so, which OID is it?
I've looked at the OIDs, but couldn't find any info about hop address (perhaps I missed it).

Comment: Have you tried anything? Check if this is helpful http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.578

Comment: Unfortunately that is another MIB, the reason CISCO-CDP-MIB should be supported is because by default it's available on all cisco devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a guaranteed way to get next-hop from the `CISCO-CDP-MIB`; the problem is that CDP only advertises one IP address for the entire machine, and there is no assurance that the IP address used by CDP is your appropriate next-hop.  I am not sure why you don't want to use `ipRouteNextHop`, but that is a fine way to discover routing information for any big-name commercial routing platform.